# calculating all possible outcomes for a sports league in python

Tags: python, probability

I'm currently trying to build an application that calculates possible outcomes for a sports league. Say I have a league with 9 Teams and there are 8 games left to play. I want to be able to determine the probabilty that any of these 9 teams finishes within a certain range (e.g. Team B finishes top 3).
The code I came up with was highly inspired by this post ([Calculating probability of a Fantasy League in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71641994/calculating-probability-of-a-fantasy-league-in-python))

I'm initially reading the current standings from a csv file and then calculate all possible outcomes. Games are best of 5 sets, so there are six diferent possible results for each game: 3:0, 3:1, 3:2, 0:3, 1:3, 2:3. I need to keep track of all of them because if, after playing all games, two teams have the same amout of points, the number of sets won decides whos ahead.
Up until now, however, I only calculated all possible outcomes without adjusting the ranking accordingly. Now the problem is that with there being 8 games with 6 possible outcomes i get about 1.7 million possible scenarios and the calculation would take roughly 50 minutes (estimated by the time it took to calculate 100k results.

Now here's my question: Is there any obvious way I can improve the runtime of my program?

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product


# simulates all possible outcomes
def simulate_league(initial_standings, remaining_games):
    possible_outcomes = list()
    for winloss_schedule in product(['www', 'wwwl', 'wwwll', 'lll', 'lllw', 'lllww'], repeat=len(remaining_games)):
        possible_outcomes.append(play_out(initial_standings, remaining_games, winloss_schedule))
    return possible_outcomes


# plays out one possible scenario
def play_out(initial_standings, remaining_games, winloss_schedule):
    standings_frame = initial_standings.copy()

    for (team_a, team_b), outcome in zip(remaining_games, winloss_schedule):
        if outcome == "www":  # 3:0 for team a
            standings_frame.loc[team_a]["points"] += 3
            standings_frame.loc[team_a]["set_win"] += 3
            standings_frame.loc[team_b]["set_loss"] += 3

        elif outcome == "wwwl":  # 3:1 for team a
            standings_frame.loc[team_a]["points"] += 3
            standings_frame.loc[team_a]["set_win"] += 3
            standings_frame.loc[team_a]["set_loss"] += 1
            standings_frame.loc[team_b]["set_win"] += 1
            standings_frame.loc[team_b]["set_loss"] += 3

        elif outcome == "wwwll":  # 3:2 for team a
            standings_frame.loc[team_a]["points"] += 2
            standings_frame.loc[team_a]["set_win"] += 3
            standings_frame.loc[team_a]["set_loss"] += 2
            standings_frame.loc[team_b]["points"] += 1
            standings_frame.loc[team_b]["set_win"] += 2
            standings_frame.loc[team_b]["set_loss"] += 3

        elif outcome == "lll":  # 3:0 for team b
            standings_frame.loc[team_b]["points"] += 3
            standings_frame.loc[team_b]["set_win"] += 3
            standings_frame.loc[team_a]["set_loss"] += 3

        elif outcome == "lllw":  # 3:1 for team b
            standings_frame.loc[team_b]["points"] += 3
            standings_frame.loc[team_b]["set_win"] += 3
            standings_frame.loc[team_b]["set_loss"] += 1
            standings_frame.loc[team_a]["set_win"] += 1
            standings_frame.loc[team_a]["set_loss"] += 3

        elif outcome == "lllww":  # 3:2 for team b
            standings_frame.loc[team_b]["points"] += 2
            standings_frame.loc[team_b]["set_win"] += 3
            standings_frame.loc[team_b]["set_loss"] += 2
            standings_frame.loc[team_a]["points"] += 1
            standings_frame.loc[team_a]["set_win"] += 2
            standings_frame.loc[team_a]["set_loss"] += 3

    return standings_frame


# reads initial standings from csv
def get_initial_standings():
    return pd.read_csv("standings.csv", sep=';', index_col="Team")


def get_remaining_games():
    remaining_games = ["A:B", "C:D", "A:D", "D:B", "E:F", "F:E", "G:E", "E:B"]
    remaining_games = [tuple(s.split(":")) for s in remaining_games]
    return remaining_games


simulate_league(get_initial_standings(), get_remaining_games())
```

Comment: why do you even need to enumerate all the possible outcomes and store into a list? Aren't you interested only in the probabilities?

Comment: yeah I am interested in probabilities, but I thought in order to figure out the probability that a certain team finishes top 3 for example i would need to look at all possible cases and count the number in which they finish top three. or is there something more efficient i'm missing?